# Scrapy carousel categories not extracting

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrap a website to get the list of categories from a carousel but it's not working.

Below is my code

```
import scrapy

class CourtsmuSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "courtsmu"
    allowed_domains = ["www.courtsmammouth.mu"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.courtsmammouth.mu"]

    def parse(self, response):
        carousel = response.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "categories_4")]').extract()

        print(f"Output: {carousel}")
```

I am getting the following output from console:

```
Output: []
```

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Your xpath is correct. Something else is wrong

Comment: Can you help me figure it out? I can't find out what is wrong

Comment: I don't know python or scrapy, but I notice 2 things: 1.  `print(f"Output: {carousel}")` what is the `f` doing?
2. scrapy probably only gets the html from the server not the updated html by JavaScript. In the server-html there is no element for your xpath.
Have a look at selenium: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/